# iOS Sending Firebase Registration Token to My App Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I currently have a functional iOS application (with react) and an app server using nodejs. So far, I am able to register with Firebase Messaging and console log my registration token through the AppDelegate.m file. And from my server, I can send my app a notification on a certain device with a POST method. However, in order to do that, I have to copy my registration token from the consolelog and paste it in the post request. Which is pointless because the token can change at any time.

I am still fairly new to this and I cannot find any examples of people sending their registration token to their app server. In all of the documentation it is always just a comment like "//If necessary send the token to your app server" with no explanation on how to go about it.

I just want to send the registration token to my server every time it refreshes so I can save it, and then send downstream messages to certain devices using their latest tokens. How do I get the Firebase token from my Obj-C AppDelegate file to my javascript server side? Can anyone help me out? Or show me an example?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and what specific error you are experiencing?

Comment: I don't even know where to start. I've tried doing some NSURL stuff with the token but I don't think that is the right way. I'm no expert in Obj-C, so I'm not sure if there is any sort of 'post' method I could do in my AppDelegate that would send over the latest token once I get it from Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, your app server will need an endpoint (say /register) that will let you make an http request posting your token to your app server.